# How to combine and append python 200+ python files into one

Tags: python, python-3.x, command, zip, subprocess

I want to combine 200+ python files and append them into one file.  This can be easily achieved with text files but these are python files.  I've read to just "egg" it or "zip" it.  But I can't seem to find anywhere examples on how to go about this, at least for [windows](http://blog.ablepear.com/2012/10/bundling-python-files-into-stand-alone.html).    Zipping it would mean that the files would just be located elsewhere.

I believe there is a github [project](https://github.com/pagekite/PyBreeder), though this is not supported for python 3.

Any ideas on how this can be achieved on Windows.  I've found almost all the solutions are in some way referencing an 'exe' whereas I don't want this in windows.  I just want the code in the files put together so I don't have to open 250 python files.

This is in reference to py files.  Which are treated differently than text files.    �  ����LL��A�   H��H��臠  H��t H��tL��H��  H�

You could in theory copy the python script to a csv but I tend to get this lovely output above.

Comment: if you combine all the files, how will you be able to import the files by name?

Comment: I'm almost positive you can just open them like .txt files.

Comment: @SuperStew They have a different extension though.  Python not likee.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre *sigh*, thats for text files.  I've tried that

Comment: @TysonDogerzonda I didn't close your question. Coldspeed did. But I don't see the difference between python files & text files. And what's the use?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Well lets say I did take that example as fact : import glob

read_files = glob.glob("*.py")

with open("C:/Users/dda/craigslist_sample/E.py", "wb") as outfile:
    for f in read_files:
        with open(f, "rb") as infile:
            outfile.write(infile.read())

Produces: H���ڌ  ��tB��qn  ��H�H��H;FsH�  .  Not exactly readable or appended.

Comment: no, .py files are text files. maybe you're reading `.pyc` files.